# How do I get a song name and a rating inside an arraylist?

Tags: string, arraylist, int

How do I make an arraylist with a song name, and a rating? Right now i just put a number infront of the song name, and then use substring to extract the rating, but I need to sort the ratings and find the songs with the highest rating - which is very complicated (in my world) using this method. Any way to link a song and a rating (1-5)? I was thinking about linkedlists, but that will be too complicated for my skills, if its the only way. All advice are very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Here is my main method:

```
    // Create band
    Band Beatles = new Band("Beatles");

    // Add musicians
    Beatles.musician.add("John Lennon");
    Beatles.musician.add("Paul McCartney");
    Beatles.musician.add("George Harrison");
    Beatles.musician.add("Ringo Starr");

    // Add songs (first number is popularity of the song)
    Beatles.songs.add("5Yesterday");
    Beatles.songs.add("5Let it be");
    Beatles.songs.add("3I Saw Her Standing There");
    Beatles.songs.add("2Misery");
    Beatles.songs.add("4Love Me Do");

    //Prints out all songs by Beatles, and their rating
    System.out.println(Beatles.musician);
    Beatles.getBandSongs();
```

Here is my Band class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Band {

public String bandName;
public ArrayList<String> musician = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

// Constructor
public Band(String bandName) {
    this.bandName = bandName;
}

public void getBandSongs(){
    for (String s : songs) {
        int rating = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,1));
        s = s.substring(1);
        System.out.println("Rating: " + rating + " - Song name: " + s);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The tags didn't really tell me - is this java or C#?

Comment: @drew_w: It's java: you can tell from the import java command!

Comment: Yep. Its Java im learning :)

Comment: @AaronB Good eye - I missed that because it isn't in the code section

Comment: Regardless, the simplest solution here is to create a class for "Song" that has song name and rating both in the class. Those can be added to the array list instead of using strings.

Comment: ^ This is exactly what I was going to say. Create a `Song` class with whatever variables you want, than use a loop to insert individual Songs one-by-one. The loop will basically be "start from the beginning, is the linked item's rating greater than my rating?, if so insert into list at that location, if not move to next entry in the list". If you need more specific help, just holla

Comment: This is the assignment description for this part. So I dont think im allowed to make a Song class:

The setup:
- Band: this is the band playing at the concert.
- Musician: a band has one or more members.
- Song: a band has written one or more songs to perform at the concert.

Let’s start with the band. The Band class has a name and furthermore contains two collections; one for the members and one for the songs. The first is a collection of Musician objects, the second a collection of Song objects. Use the collection types you see as most appropriate for the job.

Comment: If you look at the description it says "the second a collection of Song objects". Because the wording says "object" this indicates you are supposed to create a class. While everything in java is an object (even strings), it seems clear to me that you should be using classes to manage this information. Good luck!

Comment: orh thank you so much for that. makes it a lot easier. :)

Comment: @user3087630: There are occasional cases where you _do_ need to work around constraints like the way you were trying to do it before, but when we program new things, we do our best to keep things as flexible and extensible as possible. By creating classes (typically for nouns in the problem), we're giving ourselves that flexibility. For example, imagine we have a list of 10,000 songs. What if suddenly we get "Now I want them to have a `length` variable"? And so on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define a new class named Song, with two fields: a String specifying the name of the song and an integer for the song's rating. Overwrite the default compareTo() method so that songs can be compared by their ratings. You can then put the songs into an ArrayList and use a method such as Collections.max() to get the song with the highest rating. Best of luck.